# Positioning of animated element

Tags: css, animation

I created a css animation for a client [here](http://www.sytemaker.com/other-sites/weddingcars/). There are actually two separate but synchronised animations running. Currently I positioned them as "absolute" and they work fine except on mobile devices where they are pushed to the right due to the positioning. If I position them "relative" only the right text animation works whereas the left picture animation just shows a very small portion of the image. What am I missing? Your input is greatly appreciated. CSS code below:

```
/*SLIDESHOWS IMAGES*/

.slideshow
{
    list-style-type:none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

.slideshow li span
{
    width:453px;
    height:340px;
    position:absolute;
    top:91px;
    left:175px;
    color:transparent;
    background-image:url('images/banner.jpg');
    background-size:cover;
    background-repeat:none;
    opacity:0;
    z-index:0;

    -webkit-animation: myfirst 60s linear infinite 0s;

    -moz-animation: myfirst 60s linear infinite 0s;

    -o-animation: myfirst 60s linear infinite 0s;

    -ms-animation: myfirst 60s linear infinite 0s;

    animation: myfirst 60s linear infinite 0s;
}

.slideshow li:nth-child(1) span
{
    background-image:url('images/banner.jpg');
}

.slideshow li:nth-child(2) span 
{
    background-image:url('images/banner-2.jpg');
    -webkit-animation-delay:15s;
    -moz-animation-delay:15s;
    -o-animation-delay:15s;
    -ms-animation-delay:15s;
    animation-delay:15s;
}

.slideshow li:nth-child(3) span 
{
    background-image:url('images/banner-3.jpg');
    -webkit-animation-delay:30s;
    -moz-animation-delay:30s;
    -o-animation-delay:30s;
    -ms-animation-delay:30s;
    animation-delay:30s;
}

.slideshow li:nth-child(4) span 
{
    background-image:url('images/banner-4.jpg');
    -webkit-animation-delay:45s;
    -moz-animation-delay:45s;
    -o-animation-delay:45s;
    -ms-animation-delay:45s;
    animation-delay:45s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes myfirst 
{
    0% { opacity: 0; animation-timing-function: ease-in; }
    12% { opacity: 1; animation-timing-function: ease-out; }
    24% { opacity: 1; }
    40% { opacity: 0; }
    100% { opacity: 0; }
}

@-moz-keyframes myfirst 
{
    0% { opacity: 0; animation-timing-function: ease-in; }
    12% { opacity: 1; animation-timing-function: ease-out; }
    24% { opacity: 1; }
    40% { opacity: 0; }
    100% { opacity: 0; }
}

@-o-keyframes myfirst 
{
    0% { opacity: 0; animation-timing-function: ease-in; }
    12% { opacity: 1; animation-timing-function: ease-out; }
    24% { opacity: 1; }
    40% { opacity: 0; }
    100% { opacity: 0; }
}

@-ms-keyframes myfirst 
{ 
    0% { opacity: 0; animation-timing-function: ease-in; }
    12% { opacity: 1; animation-timing-function: ease-out; }
    24% { opacity: 1; }
    40% { opacity: 0; }
    100% { opacity: 0; }
}

@keyframes myfirst
{ 
    0% { opacity: 0; animation-timing-function: ease-in; }
    12% { opacity: 1; animation-timing-function: ease-out; }
    24% { opacity: 1; }
    40% { opacity: 0; }
    100% { opacity: 0; }
} 




/*SLIDESHOWS TEXT*/ 

.slogan
{
    list-style-type:none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

.slogan li div
{
    width:453px;
    height:200px;
    padding-left:20px;
    padding-top:40px;
    padding-right:10px;
    padding-bottom:10px;
    font-family:'Lucida Handwriting';
    box-shadow: 10px 10px 10px #888888;
    position:absolute;
    top:170px;
    left:675px;
    color:#cf112d;
    opacity:0;
    z-index:0;

    -webkit-animation: mysecond 60s linear infinite 0s;

    -moz-animation: mysecond 60s linear infinite 0s;

    -o-animation: mysecond 60s linear infinite 0s;

    -ms-animation: mysecond 60s linear infinite 0s;

    animation: mysecond 60s linear infinite 0s;
}

.slogan li:nth-child(1) div
{
    background-color:#ffffff;
}

.slogan li:nth-child(2) div
{
    background-color:#ffffff;
    -webkit-animation-delay:15s;
    -moz-animation-delay:15s;
    -o-animation-delay:15s;
    -ms-animation-delay:15s;
    animation-delay:15s;
}

.slogan li:nth-child(3) div
{
    background-color:#ffffff;
    -webkit-animation-delay:30s;
    -moz-animation-delay:30s;
    -o-animation-delay:30s;
    -ms-animation-delay:30s;
    animation-delay:30s;
}

.slogan li:nth-child(4) div
{
    background-color:#ffffff;
    -webkit-animation-delay:45s;
    -moz-animation-delay:45s;
    -o-animation-delay:45s;
    -ms-animation-delay:45s;
    animation-delay:45s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes mysecond
{
    0% { opacity: 0; animation-timing-function: ease-in; }
    12% { opacity: 1; animation-timing-function: ease-out; }
    24% { opacity: 1; }
    40% { opacity: 0; }
    100% { opacity: 0; }
}

@-moz-keyframes mysecond
{
    0% { opacity: 0; animation-timing-function: ease-in; }
    12% { opacity: 1; animation-timing-function: ease-out; }
    24% { opacity: 1; }
    40% { opacity: 0; }
    100% { opacity: 0; }
}

@-o-keyframes mysecond
{
    0% { opacity: 0; animation-timing-function: ease-in; }
    12% { opacity: 1; animation-timing-function: ease-out; }
    24% { opacity: 1; }
    40% { opacity: 0; }
    100% { opacity: 0; }
}

@-ms-keyframes mysecond
{
    0% { opacity: 0; animation-timing-function: ease-in; }
    12% { opacity: 1; animation-timing-function: ease-out; }
    24% { opacity: 1; }
    40% { opacity: 0; }
    100% { opacity: 0; }
}

@keyframes mysecond
{
    0% { opacity: 0; animation-timing-function: ease-in; }
    12% { opacity: 1; animation-timing-function: ease-out; }
    24% { opacity: 1; }
    40% { opacity: 0; }
    100% { opacity: 0; }
}
```

Comment: Don't post direct links in SO. edit your question and add relevant HTML code and a playground such as jsfiddle.net, jsbin.com etc.

Answer (score 0):

Right now you are positioning your elements absolute, relative to the entire page.
What you want to do is position your elements absolute, relative to the wrapper.
You can do that like this:

```
.slideshow, .slogan {
    position:relative;
}
.slideshow li span {
    top:0;
    left:0;
}
.slogan li div {
    right: 15px;
    top: 80px;
}
```

Note that I'm just adding/overwriting the relevant properties here. So integrate these changes in your CSS.